# Push notification Titanium shows whole payload instead of the actual message

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

I'm using cURL to send push notifications to appcelerator, been using this for a while without problems.

Suddenly appcelerator can't handle the JSON payload and shows the whole JSON string as an message on the actual device. This is what our curl post data looks like:

```
channel=dev&payload={"alert":"The Message","title":"Title","vibrate":true, content-available:1, "badge":"+1", "sound":"default", "id":617, "icon":"appicon"}&to_ids=everyone
```

And this is what my device shows as push notification:

```
"{
   "alert":"The Message",
   "title":"Title",
   "vibrate":true, 
    content-available:1, 
   "badge":"+1", 
   "sound":"default", 
   "id":617, 
   "icon":"appicon"
 }"
```

instead of:
"The Message"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a \n in the JSON that broke the JSON string. building a Array first then using json_encode() in PHP fixed the issue

Comment: Good to hear you've found the issue. Can you accept your own answer so that the question shows as answered?

Comment: I will when i can :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse the JSON that comes in your app. The payload **is** JSON.

So, assuming the payload comes in with the variable `data`, you need to do this:

```
alert(JSON.parse(data).alert);
```

This will display the alert property of the payload.

Comment: This is only for when the app is open right ? I'm talking about the notification in the message center of ios and android when the app is closed.

Comment: this is in app code yes. If it is in notification center the payload is incorrect :) But I see you already found that